# Different results in queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two similar queries:

```
select COUNT(*), to_char(start_time,'YYYYMMDD') from EXECUTIONS where 
to_char(start_time,'YYYYMMDD') >= '20200101' and
to_char(start_time,'YYYYMMDD') <= '20200131' 
AND SERVER IN ('PRO','PRE','DE')
group by to_char(start_time,'YYYYMMDD') ORDER BY to_char(start_time,'YYYYMMDD')  ASC ;
---------
select
    SERVER,
    APP,
    sum(case when ended_status = 16 then 1 else 0 end) OK,
    sum(case when ended_status = 32 then 1 else 0 end) BAD,
        count(ended_status) TOTAL
from EXECUTIONS
where start_time >= '20200101' and start_time <= '20200131'
and SERVER in ('PRO','PRE','DE')
group by
    SERVER,
    APP
order by SERVER,APP;
```

I've saw that in the last query the last day of the month (2020131) is not included in the query.

I can't understand why. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 3):

It has a time component.  The correct logic is:

```
where start_time >= '20200101' and
      start_time <  '20200201'
```

This is safe for both dates and date/times.  I strongly recommend using inequalities like this for *all* date comparisons, so you don't have to worry about whether or not a time component is part of the value.  And the above is index safe.